# Binding values between MVC and Angular

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

**Scenario**

I am using Angular, purely for validation on my front-end, and MVC model binding

**Example**

```
<div ng-class="{'has-error': Contact.FirstName.$invalid}">
    <input type="text"
           name="@Html.NameFor(m => m.FirstName)"
           id="@Html.IdFor(m => m.FirstName)"
           value="@Model.FirstName"
           ng-model="model.person.firstName"
           required />
</div>
```

**Problem**

`value` is populated by MVC on postback, but because `model.person.firstName` is initially `null`, the value is cleared when the document finishes loading, and angular has flushed all of it's magic into the view.

**Question**

How can I keep `ng-model` (in order to keep validation working) and pre-populate the `value` of the field?

Comment: You need to call a service in your back-end from within Angular, and then use the result in your Controller.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship data is not being delivered to the front-end via a service. That would be trivial. The problem is that the values are being bound to the view, long before angular get's a hold of it, so angular just ignores what's in the view and does it's thing

Comment: Right. Don't do that. It circumvents AngularJS, which is why you are having problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The values have to be initialised in the controller** and not in the view.

#### Option 1 :

You can try `ng-init`. See [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30715492/getting-and-passing-mvc-model-data-to-angularjs-controller)

#### Option 2 :

Another way is to create a service directly in the `.cshtml` file in a `<script></script>` tag. Filling the data of the service with Razor and then get this values with your Angular controller.

> In my opinion the second way is cleaner.