# Use Angular to toggle the display of certain items from a List of MVC Models

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

So I am building a simple MVC application that displays a grid of icons.

The View gets passed a List of models, then uses a `@foreach` loop to display them in the following manner

```
<div class="rows">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="column">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.size)
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

I want to be able to hide/show certain items based on their content, and I want to be able to toggle that with a button.

So for example, I might want to have a button that when pressed, will hide all columns displaying an item where `item.info == SomeValue`

I've messed around with `ng-hide` and `ng-if` but I can't figure out a way to only hide certain items.

Here is the angular component I've come up with:

```
    var app = angular.module(toggleDisplay, []);

    app.controller("displayMode", function($scope) {
        $scope.displayLarge;
    });
```

But as I said I can only figure out how to hide the whole list. I want to use Angular to be able to toggle it so that, for example, it only displays the item when `item.size == large`. So if the box is unchecked it displays the whole list, but if I check it, it only displays large items.

I've never worked with angular before and I can't figure out a pattern to make this work. It's possible I'm coming at it all wrong.

Here's the app that hides the whole list:

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module(toggleDisplay, []);

    app.controller("displayMode", function($scope) {
        $scope.displayAll;
    });
</script>

<div ng-app="toggleDisplay" ng-controller="displayMode">

    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="displayAll"/>

    <div class="rows">
        <div class="ng-hide" ng-hide="displayAll">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <div class="column">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.size)
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I'd probably recommend letting angular handle your models as well if possible and use [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

Comment: @csp713 I thought about that too, but I couldn't figure out how to get all the data from the list of models into an angular component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `ng-repeat` here for that you have to [serialize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22039421/5621827) your model and that can be done using [newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)  something like

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module("toggleDisplay", []);

    app.controller("displayMode", function($scope) {
        $scope.init=function(model){
              $scope.data=model;
      };
    });
</script>


<input type="checkbox" ng-model="displayLarge"/>

<div class="rows" ng-init="init(@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))">
    <div class="column" ng-repeat="item in data" ng-hide="displayLarge && item.size != 'large'">
        {{item.size}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does look promising. I'm having some issues getting it to bind correctly with ng-repeat. I verified that it was serializing the models correctly by just putting the @JsonConvery.SerializedObject(Model) in a <p></p> (the contents were correct), but when I try to use ng-repeat all that gets printed out is a single "{{item.size}}"

I will update the OP with the entirely of the cshtml file and a screenshot of the output.

Comment: `var app = angular.module(toggleDisplay, []);`

needed to be 

`var app = angular.module("toggleDisplay", []);`

Answer (score 0):

you didn't mentioned exactly what do you want !

but i think you want this :

first of all when you use angular js you don't need MVC foreach.

see : [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

then you should use [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) angular directive on every repeated item (*column*)

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module(toggleDisplay, []);

    app.controller("displayMode", function($scope) {
        $scope.displayAll;
        $scope.data = Model; // get Model from Mvc ( i don't know mvc )
    });
</script>

    <div ng-app="toggleDisplay" ng-controller="displayMode">

        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="displayAll"/>

        <div class="rows">
                    <div class="column" 
                        ng-repeat={item in data} ng-show="!displayAll || item.size == large">
                        {{item.size}}
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

if you stuck in how sync mvc model and angular controller see this question :

[Getting and passing MVC Model data to AngularJS controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30715492/getting-and-passing-mvc-model-data-to-angularjs-controller)

***represent model by json object***